# How does one find the number of subsets for a particular row, in a 2D list with python? Can collections' Counter function be used?

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, tuples, subset

Please excuse the title, it is hard to express the problem correctly without showing an example.

I have a very large 2D array with rows of varying sizes, for example:

```
big2DArray =
[["a","g","r"],
["a","r"],
["p","q"],
["a", "r"]]
```

I need to return a dictionary, it has to look something like this:

```
{('a','g','r'): 1, ('a', 'r'): 3, ('p', 'q'):1}
```

The `('a', 'r')` tuple is found to have a value of 3, since it occurs twice as itself and once as a subset (less than or equal) to the tuple `('a', 'g', 'r')`.

Normally I would use something like this:

```
dictCounts = Counter(map(tuple, big2DArray))
```

Which, for big2Darray, would give:

```
{('a','g','r'): 1, ('a', 'r'): 2, ('p', 'q'):1}
```

My question is this, can Collections' Counter function be used so that it gives the counts for the subsets as well, like explained above?  If not, is there any *comparably efficient* method to return my desired dictionary output for subsets?

Thanks so much!

Edit 1:  Just for further clarity! I do not want to return all subsets, such as {('a','g'): 1, ('a','r'):3}, and so on.  I only want to return the counts for the unique rows in the 2D array. So in this case the counts for: ('a','g','r'), ('a','r'), ('p','q').

Edit 2: The row ["a","r"] should be treated as equivalent to ["r", "a"], and so should the tuples ('a','r') and ('r','a')

Comment: Are you sure you really want to get **all** subset? It's a exponentially huge number.

Comment: Can you also clarify whether you need `('g', 'r')`. This is technically a subset but does not appear in your output.

Comment: Edited the question, I hope that makes it more clear!

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. It uses `defaultdict` instead of `Counter`. The dictionary keys are [`frozensets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset). If you need ordered tuple dictionary keys, see [@RoadRunner's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721673/9209546).

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
from collections import defaultdict

big2DArray = [["a","g","r"],
              ["a","r"],
              ["p","q"],
              ["a", "r"]]

arr_new = [[set(i) for k in range(2, len(j)+1) \
            for i in combinations(j, k)] for j in big2DArray]

full_list = set(map(frozenset, big2DArray))

counter = defaultdict(int)

for i in range(len(big2DArray)):
    for j in full_list:
        if j in arr_new[i]:
            counter[frozenset(j)] += 1

# defaultdict(int,
#             {frozenset({'a', 'r'}): 3,
#              frozenset({'a', 'g', 'r'}): 1,
#              frozenset({'p', 'q'}): 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set.issubset`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html) with `collections.Counter` here.

**Demo:**

```
from collections import Counter

big2DArray = [["a","g","r"],
              ["a","r"],
              ["p","q"],
              ["a", "r"],
              ["r", "a"]]

counts = Counter(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), big2DArray))

count_lst = list(counts)
for i, k1 in enumerate(count_lst):
    rest = count_lst[:i] + count_lst[i+1:]
    for k2 in rest:
        if set(k1).issubset(k2):
            counts[k1] += 1

print(counts)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({('a', 'r'): 4, ('a', 'g', 'r'): 1, ('p', 'q'): 1})
```

In the above code, in order to make sure `["r", "a"]` and `["a","r"]` are equivalent, you can sort them beforehand, and add them as tuples to `Counter()`.

The other more efficient way would be to use `frozenset`, as shown in the other answer.

Comment: Since `('a', 'r')` and `('r', 'a')` are considered equivalent for user's algorithm, is it a good idea to have `Counter` keys as tuples? More a question for OP. This is why I went down frozenset route.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis Yeah I was unsure about that as well. This could be fixed with `tuple(sorted(x))` or `frozenset` as you've done. I'll update the answer.